# Use Group By and Aggregate Function in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I am looking for a Solution to how to use Group by Aggregate Functions together in Pyspark?
My Dataframe looks like this:

```
df = sc.parallelize([
    ('23-09-2020', 'CRICKET'),
    ('25-11-2020', 'CRICKET'),
    ('13-09-2021', 'FOOTBALL'),
    ('20-11-2021', 'BASKETBALL'),
    ('12-12-2021', 'FOOTBALL')]).toDF(['DATE', 'SPORTS_INTERESTED'])
```

I want to apply group by on the SPORTS_INTERESTED Column and select MIN of date From DATE Column .
Below is the Query i am using

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import  min
df=df.groupby('SPORTS_INTERESTED').agg(count('SPORTS_INTERESTED').alias('FIRST_COUNT'),(F.min('DATE').alias('MIN_OF_DATE_COLUMN'))).filter((col('FIRST_COUNT')> 1))
```

But when i am applying the above Query , I dont know why it is giving MAX date rather than MIN date in Output values
DESIRED OUTPUT

```
## +-----------------+-------------------+
## |SPORTS_INTERESTED| MIN_OF_DATE_COLUMN|    
## +------+----------+-------------------+
## |  CRICKET        |23-09-2020         |
## +------+----------+-------------------+
## | FOOTBALL        |13-09-2021         |
   +-----------------+-------------------+
```

Output i am getting:

```
 ## +-----------------+----------------------+
    ## |SPORTS_INTERESTED| MIN_OF_DATE_COLUMN|    
    ## +------+----------+-------------------+
    ## |  CRICKET        |25-11-2020         |
    ## +------+----------+-------------------+
    ## | FOOTBALL        |12-12-2021         |
       +-----------------+-------------------+
```

BOTH COLUMNS ARE OF STRING DATATYPE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, convert string to date format, and then apply min:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[
    ('23-09-2020', 'CRICKET'),
    ('25-11-2020', 'CRICKET'),
    ('13-09-2021', 'FOOTBALL'),
    ('20-11-2021', 'BASKETBALL'),
    ('12-12-2021', 'FOOTBALL')    
], schema=['DATE', 'SPORTS_INTERESTED'])

df = df.withColumn("DATE", F.to_date("DATE", format="dd-MM-yyyy"))
df = df.groupBy("SPORTS_INTERESTED").agg(F.min("DATE").alias("MIN_OF_DATE"))

[Out]:
+-----------------+-----------+
|SPORTS_INTERESTED|MIN_OF_DATE|
+-----------------+-----------+
|BASKETBALL       |2021-11-20 |
|FOOTBALL         |2021-09-13 |
|CRICKET          |2020-09-23 |
+-----------------+-----------+
```

Comment: hi @Azhar Khan But any idea why when Date Column is in string datatype why it is working differently

Comment: Like when i am applying MAX it is giving min result and when applyimg MIN give max result

Comment: I see that you are getting min values by string comparison: `CRICKET -> 23-09-2020` and `FOOTBALL -> 12-12-2021`.